# C++ delete error

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue, delete-operator

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to code a linked-list based queue. My test program worked fine until I added delete to the dequeue function. Then I get the error: 
**malloc: *** error for object 0x7f8a61403a00: pointer being freed was not allocated**

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <string>
#include "queue.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


Queue::Queue() { // Constructs a new empty queue.
    current_size = 0;   // number of elements in queue
    front_p = NULL; // first element in queue
    back_p = NULL;  // last element in queue
}

Queue::Queue( const Queue& q ) {// Copy constructor.
    // nothing to copy if queue empty
    if (q.current_size == 0) {
        return;
    }
    // queue not empty
    else {
        node * p = q.front_p;
        node * n;
        // assign front pointer
        n = new node(p -> data, NULL);
        front_p = n;
        p = p -> next;
        // middle elements
        while (p -> next != NULL) {
            n -> next = p;
            n = new node(p -> data, NULL);
            p = p -> next;
        }
        // assign back pointer
        n = new node(p -> data, NULL);
        back_p = n;
        current_size = q.current_size;
    }
}

void Queue::enqueue( int item ) { // Enqueues <item> to back
    node * n = new node(item, NULL);

    // first item in queue, front & back ptrs point to same element
    if (back_p == NULL) {
        front_p = n;
        back_p = n;
    }
    else {
        back_p -> next = n;
        back_p = n;
    }
    current_size++;
}

int Queue::dequeue() { // removes and returns the front item.
    // empty queue
    if (current_size == 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    int item = front();
    node * p = front_p;
    if (current_size == 1) {
        front_p = NULL;
        back_p = NULL;
        delete p;
        current_size--;
        return item;
    }
    else {
        front_p = front_p -> next;
        delete p;
        current_size--;
        return item;
    }
}
```

test file

```
//test  file
#include <iostream> 
#include "queue.h"
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    Queue q1;
    cout << "Create a new queue q1" << endl;
    cout << "Size of q1 \t" << q1.size() << endl;
    cout << "Is q1 empty? \t" << q1.empty() << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "enqueue \t1,2,3,4,5" << endl;
    q1.enqueue(1);
    q1.enqueue(2);
    q1.enqueue(3);
    q1.enqueue(4);
    q1.enqueue(5);
    cout << "front of q1 \t" << q1.front() << endl;
    cout << "size of q1 \t" << q1.size() << endl << endl;

    cout << "q2 is a deep copy of q1" << endl;
    Queue q2(q1);
    cout << "front of q2 \t" << q2.front() << endl;
    cout << "size of q2 \t" << q2.size() << endl << endl;

    cout << "removed 4 from q1" << endl;
    q1.remove(4);
    cout << "removed 2 from q2" << endl;
    q2.remove(2);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "print out remaining elements of q1" << endl;
    int N = q1.size();
    for(int i=0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << q1.dequeue() << " ";    
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "print out remaining elements of q2" << endl;
    N = q2.size();
    for(int i=0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << q2.dequeue() << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

header file

```
    class Queue
    {
    public:

        Queue(); // Constructs a new empty queue.
        Queue( const Queue& q );// Copy constructor.
        ~Queue();// Destructor.

        void enqueue( int item ); // Enqueues <item>.
        int dequeue();  // Dequeues the front item.
        int front();  // Returns the front item without dequeuing it.
        bool empty();  // Returns true iff the queue contains no items.
        int size();  // Returns the current number of items in the queue.
        bool remove(int item); // If <item> occurs in the queue, removes the 
      // first occurrence of <item> and returns true; otherwise returns false.

    private:
        class node  // node type for the linked list 
        {
       public:
           node(int new_data, node * next_node){
              data = new_data ;
              next = next_node ;
           }
           int data ;
           node * next ;
    };

    node * front_p ; // pointer to the (node containing the) next item 
              //  which to be dequeud, or NULL if the queue is empty.

    node * back_p ; // pointer to the (node containing the) last item 
              // which was enqueued, or NULL if the queue is empty.

    int current_size ; // current number of elements in the queue.
};
```

Comment: `I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to code a linked-list based queue`  Your new to C++ and this is one of your first assignments?  Anyway, did you use your debugger to debug the code?  You can't just dump all of the code and have someone else do the debugging for you.

Comment: `Queue q2(q1);` Where is your `Queue` copy constructor?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Probably a case of trying to run when you cannot crawl

Comment: Does your constructor initialize `front_p`, `back_p`, and `current_size`?

Comment: Related: None of your `Queue` member variables are initialized in your copy constructor if the rhs is an empty queue.

Comment: There also is no assignment operator defined for `Queue`.  Also, your destructor could just be `while (!empty()) dequeue();`

Comment: You really do need to go through your code and remove the redundancies.  For example, your copy constructor just needs to call `enqueue` in a loop, as well as your destructor just needing to call `dequeue` in a loop.  It makes the code much smaller, easier to understand, and your bugs (if any) are isolated to 2 or 3 functions, not the whole class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other issues with the code, but the most immediate one is that your copy-constructor is broken.

In this cycle

```
    while (p -> next != NULL) {
        n -> next = p;
        n = new node(p -> data, NULL);
        p = p -> next;
    }
```

`p` is a pointer to an element of a *source* queue `q`. Meanwhile, `n` is an element of the *new* queue. By doing `n -> next = p;` you are making the new queue nodes to link into the source queue node chain. This creates a completely nonsensical node linkage structure, which falls apart later.

Comment: +1This means when finished copying the second-to-last node `next` pointer in the target queue points to the last node in the source queue, but the back-pointer of the target queue points to an otherwise unreferenced node. (I was halfway through writing this up when began posting your chain, ; no sense in duplicating it).

Comment: @ssync - all your copy constructor really needs to do is 1) initialize the members and 2), just call `enqueue` in a loop.  You don't need to run through the gauntlet of all of this pointer manipulation:  `node * p = q.front_p;  while (p -> next){         enqueue(p->data); p = p->next;}`